# String comparison in [[ ]] failing when target string contains quotes

Tags: bash, while-loop

I am very confused as to why this while loop does not terminate, even though `stack_status` looks like it is equal to `CREATE_COMPLETE`. Did I forget something trivial?

```
stack_status=""
while [[ $stack_status != "CREATE_COMPLETE" ]]; 
do
   stack_status=$(aws cloudformation --region us-east-2 describe-stacks --stack-name ${stack_name} --query Stacks[0].StackStatus);   
   echo "Waiting for stack to complete"; 
   echo $stack_status;   
   sleep 5; 
done
```

Output

```
Waiting for stack to complete
"CREATE_COMPLETE"
Waiting for stack to complete
"CREATE_COMPLETE"
Waiting for stack to complete
"CREATE_COMPLETE"
Waiting for stack to complete
"CREATE_COMPLETE"
```

Comment: Your string is `"CREATE_COMPLETE"`, not `CREATE_COMPLETE`; they don't match.

Comment: Also, `echo $stack_status` is itself buggy; see [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Comment: (Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/; it'll automatically identify quoting errors, among others).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I will be using shellcheck.net from now on for sure. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the double quotes to be considered literal data, put single quotes around them.

```
while [[ $stack_status != '"CREATE_COMPLETE"' ]]; do
```

Comment: omg, that was it.

Comment: I have to wait a few minutes before I am able to, SO won't let me yet.